# List datas in arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have a arraylist variable this variable returns like this data:

```
[user01:message1, user02:message2, user01:message3]
```

I want to list each item,I'll put to log screen like this

```
"user01 said:message1"
"user02 said:message2"
"user01 said:message3"
```

How can I list like this ?

Edit:

This is my arraylist class

```
 class Message
    {
        public String message, sender;
        public Message (String msg, String from)
        {
            // check here that msg and from are not null. If so, use a default value or throw an NullPointerException
            message = msg;
            sender = from;
        }
        // Just a utility method for printing out the Message to System.out
        public String toString () { return sender+":"+message; }
    }
```

And this is the list:

```
Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>> table = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>>();
```

Comment: how about `message3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over each message and print its contents.

```
for (Message message : messages) {    
  System.out.println(message.sender + " said: " + message.message);
}
```

Comment: If someone puts ":" to message ?

Comment: parts[0] + " said: " + parts[1]. Or data.replaceAll(":", " said:") and then just print that.

Comment: I am getting compiler error Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Message to String

Comment: you need to give more context here... what type is your arraylist, etc.

Comment: Well,I can't use like this.Because I will add them to list adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a advance for loop to iterate to all the element inside the List and use `replaceFirst` method to insert the string before the colon

**sample:**

```
for (String data : list) 
   Log.d("", data.replaceFirst(":", " said:"));
```

Now `replaceFirst` will only replace the first occurence of colon if the message have `colon` it wont get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with something like this,

```
List<String> al = Arrays.asList("user01:message1", "user02:message2",
    "user01:message3");
for (String str : al) {
    Log.d(String.format("\"%s\"%n", str.replaceFirst(":", " said:")));
}
```

Output is

```
"user01 said:message1"
"user02 said:message2"
"user01 said:message3"
```

Comment: If someone puts ":" to message ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   String [] split;

   for(String s: al){
       split = s.split(":");

       System.out.println(split[0] + " said :" + split[1]);
   }
```